# Show that a set is connected

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

Show that $S:= \{ x+iy \;|\; x = 0 \text{ or } x>0 , y = \sin(\frac{1}{x}) \} $ is connected, even though there are points in $S$ that cannot be connected by any curve in $S$

**Attempt**: Suppose $S$ is disconnected. By definition there exists two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $S$ is contained in $A \cup B$ and $S$ is not contained in neither $A$ nor $B$.

This is where I'm stuck. Somehow I have to arrive at a contradiction or show that no such sets $A, B$ exist but don't know how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This set isn’t properly defined. What is $y$ when $x=0$? You probably mean to only have $x>0$ and to include $yi$ where $|y|\leq1$.

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake in trying to express the set more compactly. The question is an exercise from Complex Analysis 3rd edition, by Bak and Newman. It says "Let $S = \{ x+iy \; :  \; x=0 \text{ or } x >0 , y= \sin(1/x) \} $ ".

Comment: Would you like the magic words, or just a hint?

Comment: Either would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [Topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), and trying to prove that it is connected. Here is a way that may help you.

Define, $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ by, $X=\{(0,0)\}\cup B$ where $B=\{(x,y):0<x<1,y=\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})\}$.

Clearly, the set $B$ is the graph of the function, $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by, $f(x)=(x,\sin (\frac{\pi}{x}))$.

Again it is clear that $f$ is continuous and $(0,1]$ is connected so $B$ is connected, and hence $\overline{B}$ is [connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678032/the-closure-of-a-connected-set-in-a-topological-space-is-connected). Also, $(0,0)$ is a limit point of $B$ and $B\subset X \subset \overline{B}$. Hence $X$ is [connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328980/proposed-proof-of-if-a-subset-b-subset-bara-and-a-is-connected-then).

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you! The book I'm using doesn't have the propositions you used, but it does provide the definition of a disconnected set and then mentions that a set is called connected if it's not disconnected. This is why I tried proof by contradiction.

Comment: $B$ connected implies $\bar{B}$ is connected? Perhaps you meant to link a proof to this?

Comment: @michael thank you for correcting me. I have updated the link.