# Let X be a space and C a connected subset of X. Suppose C $\subset$ D $\subset$ Cbar . Then D is connected.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

We know that C is a connected subset of X, iff C is connected in the subspace topology. Therefore, from the definition of subspace topology, we know that there should be a V subset of C, and there should exist an open set U that belong to the topology, s.t. $V = $U $\cap$ C$.

Also, $C \subset D \subset$ $C^{bar}$, from here we can say that one of them in dense in D, I think it will be C bar. Then, i need to show that there doesn't exist a separation of D, i.e. there doesnt exist non empty sets U and V in D. I am having a hard time figuring how to relate those and show D is connected or not separated.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1328980/34930

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proposed proof of: If $A \subset B \subset \bar{A}$ and $A$ is connected, then $B$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328980/proposed-proof-of-if-a-subset-b-subset-bara-and-a-is-connected-then)

Comment: yeah, its the same question. I will see that and do mine. thanks a lot